# change timestamps from mysql format to unix - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to change a mysql timestamp from mysql format (ie: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) to unix format.

How would I write a query to change the datatype from timestamp to int, and convert all records to unix format in one fell swoop ?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Do you mean change the database column to be the unix timestamp? You could just create a new column of bigint unsigned type to store that. If you want to keep it as the datetime datatype though there is the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: What makes you think mysql stores timestamps as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'?  It doesn't by default, unless someone is using a character format instead.  This is just how it displays the internal binary (non-printable) format to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a new column of type `INT UNSIGNED` to store the new UNIX time, you can run an `UPDATE` command using [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) like the following:

```
UPDATE table
SET
   newDateColumn = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(oldDateColumn)
```

Where `oldDateColumn` is of type `date`. Then afterwords you can drop the `oldDateColumn` column (if you need/want to).